# Android error: WARN/Looper Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x10 on wake read pipe

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm developing a game for Android that uses a native library. In the last week or so I've been sometimes getting in my logcat a whole lot of these warnings:

01-08 13:46:20.390: WARN/Looper(6100): Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x10 on wake read pipe.
01-08 13:46:20.410: WARN/Looper(6100): Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x10 on wake read pipe.
01-08 13:46:20.410: WARN/Looper(6100): Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x10 on wake read pipe.
01-08 13:46:20.410: WARN/Looper(6100): Ignoring unexpected epoll events 0x10 on wake read pipe.

I use AsyncTask called from native a lot to download many files in the background. I didn't find anything relevant. What should I be checking in my code that cause that kind of warning? Thanks for your help!